# need a trigger when application is installed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to know if there is any broadcast or other way in which we can Identify that the application is now installed.

I tried intent.action_package_install and intent.action_package_added but I am not able to receive the Broadcast.

Comment: Can you show us your AndroidManifest and your BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: @ Jordi Coscolla 



Manifest :-
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

Comment: Code :-
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

String action = getIntent.getAction();

if(action.equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH")){                       System.out.println("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH");
else if(action.equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL")){
            System.out.println("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL");
        }

}

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do.
Regarding ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED, documentation says : "Note that the newly installed package does not receive this broadcast.". Check more on 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED

Comment: Thanks I missed the that part in description. But is there any other way to get this.

Comment: I don't think you can do. If you have some initializations to do, you'd be better do them on application first launch.

Comment: I want to start service as soon as its installed.